# How to update ref state after its constituent ref chnages?

Tags: vue.js, ref

**I have two variables:**

- color    `const color = ref('blue')`
- classes  `` const classes = ref(`bg-${color.value}-500 font-bold`) ``

And a function that changes them

- function  `const changeColor = () => {color.value = 'green'}`

**The first one updates, the second one doesn't!! How do I update the second one?**

here is a demo
https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-dream-p1wrb8?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

```
<template>
  <button @click="changeColor">{{ classes }} has color: {{ color }}</button>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from "vue";
export default {
  setup() {
    const color = ref("blue");
    const classes = ref(`bg-${color.value}-500 font-bold`);
    const changeColor = () => {
      color.value = "green";
    };
    return { color, classes, changeColor };
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on your criteria, I suggest you use [computed()](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html) for `classes`:

```js
import { ref, computed } from "vue";
export default {
  setup() {
    ...
    const classes = computed(()=>`bg-${color.value}-500 font-bold` )
    ...
  },
};
```

This allows `classes` to update whenever the value of `color` changes.